# Jquery, get dynamic attribute for dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

This is an extension to a previous question which was answered. But have a different need/issue. Here is the jquery code:

```
$("#deletec-box").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height:230,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function() {
            window.location = $('#deletec-confirm').attr('href');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#deletec-confirm").click(function() {
    $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Here is the original link:

```
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" id="deletec-confirm">Delete</a>
```

But I have multiple links on one page with the same id. So I changed the link to:

```
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" id="deletec-confirm10">Delete</a>
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" id="deletec-confirm9">Delete</a>
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" id="deletec-confirm12">Delete</a>
```

How would I dynamically get the link the person clicked on to get the dialog? Right now it gets the url like so:

```
window.location = $('#deletec-confirm').attr('href');
```

Do I change the id to a class in the link? Or is there another way to dynamically select the id of the link so I can keep the id= attribute for each link?

Side note, if this is considered duplicate please let me know what I need to do.

Comment: so you no longer have any items on the page with the same ID correct?

Comment: @kasdega That is correct, each id is different/dynamic. So just dont know what each id would be except it starts with deletec-confirm

Comment: a selector for that would be $('input[id^="deletec-confirm"]') but Edgar gave you a better way to do it with a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use a common `class` to all your links. like this:

```
<div id="deletec-box">Are you sure you want to delete?</div> 
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" class="deletec-confirm">Delete</a>
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" class="deletec-confirm">Delete</a>
<a href="?action=delc&cid=2" class="deletec-confirm">Delete</a>
```

Then, you could store the 'clicked link' with `.data()`

```
$("#deletec-box").dialog({
    ...
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function(idx) {
            window.location = $('#deletec-box').data('openerLink').attr('href');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        ...
    }
});

//By binding with a class, you bind once for all
$(".deletec-confirm").click(function() {
    $("#deletec-box").data("openerLink", $(this)); //Store the link in the dialog
    $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
    return true;
});
```

The advantage of using `.data()` is that you don't use global vars, and store what you want only where you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adhere to HTML/XHTML standards you'll need to adjust the `id` attributes so they are unique, or remove them and use a class for your selectors instead as I have done in the example below.

Here's a basic approach that will alert the `href` attribute values, adjust as necessary:

```
var $sender;

$("#deletec-box").dialog({
    ...
    buttons: {
        "Confirm": function(idx) {
            alert($sender.attr('href'));
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        ...
    }
});

$(".deletec-confirm").click(function() {
    $sender = $(this);
    $("#deletec-box").dialog("open");
    return true;
});
```

Combined with this HTML as an example:

```
<div id="deletec-box">Are you sure you want to delete?</div> 
<a href="#1" class="deletec-confirm">Delete</a> 
<a href="#2" class="deletec-confirm">Delete</a>
```

Comment: I might be wrong because the question sort of glaces over it but I think he's already changed it so that each delete link has a different id.